# get number of div elements

Tags: php, database

I fetched some div elements from database with this code :

```
 <?php
$getTickets = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM usersTicket");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getTickets)) {
    ?>
        <div class="tickets">
            <div class="ticket"><?php echo $row['ticketText'] ?></div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

How can I get the number of these `div` elements that fetched from database ?

Comment: do you mean count of `usertickets`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want to get the number of divs returned from the database.

```
 $number_of_divs = mysqli_num_rows($getTickets);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the number of `<div class='tickets'>` in the web page !

Comment: @Mehdi as long as I understand you are printing out those divs in a while loop. This loop is looping for the number of data you fetched from the database and in each loop you print a div element with class='tickets' on your webpage. So at the end the number of loops and the number of divs will be exactly identical and equal. So getting the number of rows is the same as getting the number of divs. If you know the number of rows, you also know the number of divs. If you mean something else please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ticketclassnr = $(".tickets").length;
});
```